# What are some examples of functions that are faster to verify than to compute?

Tags: probability, proof-verification, algorithms

I'm aware to [Freivalds' algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freivalds%27_algorithm) to verify matrix multiplication.
Are there more functions like that?
(Also probabilistic verifications)

Comment: Beware that Freivald's algorithm is probabilistic, so not performing true verification.

Comment: Simply verify that the result is correct.

Comment: All NP complete problems are believed to be faster to verity than to solve.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem

Comment: @YvesDaoust thanks. 1. I'm interested in probabilistic verifications as well; 2. Of course for NP, are there more, not-NP examples? Thank you.

Comment: @NewB: if you don't say it, we can't guess.

Comment: See also [probabilistically checkable proofs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probabilistically_checkable_proof)

Answer (score 3):

One example would be the function $R$ mapping a polynomial $p \in \mathbb Q[X]$ to its set of rational roots (in  the power set  $\mathcal P(\mathbb Q)$).

Answer (score 3):

Not counting the efficient theoretical algorithms, resolution of a dense linear system is $O(N^3)$ while verification is $O(N^2)$.

Integer factorization is hard. Verification is immediate.

Finding three integer cubes that sum to $42$ took over a million hours of computation (and AFAIK was only performed once in the history of computing). Verification is done in a microsecond.

Comment: Just a note on the hardness of integer factorization: apparently it is generally believed to not be NP-hard, but is also believed to not be in P. So it might be one of the legendary NP-intermediate problems!

Answer (score 2):

A relatively famous example of this is found in [Lander, L. J., & Parkin, T. R. (1966)](https://cdn.paperpile.com/blog/img/lander-1966-1200x675.png?v=18), a 2-sentence proof, settling a conjecture that even Euler could not resolve. The problem is to find four fifth powers that sum to another fifth power. Easy to check but hard to find. Similar examples can be found with other tricky Diophantine equations.

To reframe this into a problem about functions, you could ask about the zeroes of $f(v,w,x,y,z)=v^5+w^5+x^5+y^5-z^5$.

Comment: Better ask for *some* zero. Checking that you found all of them is more challenging.